# Amateur Questions

Tags: solidity, tokens, games

I am trying to develop a cryptocurrency for use in a game I am also developing.
So I am not looking to monetize off of this cryptocurrency. Its primary purpose is game functionality.

If so, should I consider creating a coin instead of token? I don't plan on having real money tied to any of it. At least not in the near future.
Also, what are the costs? I can't seem to find an answer on what costs are associated. All the different websites just give an overall cost.
I can forgo listing this on any exchange? Since I am just using this for a game I am developing. And the game is free to play. And the currency is given for new users for free. The currency is merely allow the game to function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say that your only cost will be deploying the contract.. but the users will have to pay gas everytime they do anything in game that requires a change of state in the Blockchain

Using a "nft" or a "coin"?

In the core both are essentially a smart contract but following a different EIP.. so you could choose the one that gets the best of your game

Ie.

An erc1155 in a chain like polygon could allow you to have a collection of your items in game with different purposes with unique supply per token.. and you will be able to see this in opensea

An erc20 token... Not so nice for gamificación haha only serves the purpose of a coin

As of which Blockchain? If you're not going to monetize the token, I suggest a Blockchain like polygon since their gas cost is way way lower than Ethereum mainer.. you could search for other L2 networks too

Comment: will they have to pay gas even if it's a coin? I thought gas was only for tokens? I am not using NFT. I am using either coin or token. That is something I am still trying to decide....coin or token. But definitely FT.

Comment: Looks like I was wrong. Coins also have gas fees.

Comment: Yes, anything that changes the state of a Blockchain cost gas

Comment: can you create an ERC-20 token that costs a fraction of Ethereum token?

Comment: You can only set a mint price but that doesn't mean it will always stay the same haha, the market dictates the price after mint

Comment: Got it! Thanks ! = )